# How to emit an array that updates across connected clients with socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, chatroom

I'm trying to display the usernames of all connected clients in my chat room by adding their username to an array. Currently, my code will just update the user-list with the most recent username to have joined, rather than add the username to the array, leading me to believe the array isn't actually being emitted in the way I anticipate?

script.js:

```
var items = [];
var user = user;
if (!user) {
  user = prompt('Please choose a username:');
  items.push(user);
  socket.emit('theitems', {
      items: items
});
  if (!user) {
    alert('Your name has been set to "Anonymous"');
    user = "Anonymous"
        items.push(user);
  } else {
      alert('Your name has been set to "'+ user +'"');
  } 
}
console.log(items);

socket.on('theitems', function (data) {
      $('.dispUser').html(data.items);
    });
```

index.js

```
server(socket('theitems', ctx => { console.log(ctx.data); ctx.io.emit('theitems', ctx.data); }));
```

---

Updated code that uses the server as a 'master array'.

This code (+ some of the above) has solved my issue.

index.js (server):

```
var newitems = [];
server(socket('theitems', ctx => { newitems.push(ctx.data); console.log(ctx.data); ctx.io.emit('theitems', newitems); }));
```

script.js (client):

```
socket.emit('theitems', user);

socket.on('theitems', function (data) {
      $('.dispUser').html(data);
      console.log(data);
    });
```

Comment: Sorry; my idea is that there’s an array (items[]) that stores the usernames of clients as they join and leave, and displays that array to a <div>, so, that, as clients join and leave, their usernames are displayed/removed, aka, an “online users” section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Sorry; my idea is that there’s an array (items[]) that stores the usernames of clients as they join and leave, and displays that array to a , so, that, as clients join and leave, their usernames are displayed/removed, aka, an “online users” section.

To do that, you have two choices.  Whenever the array changes on the server you have to either send a new copy of the full array of names to each client and they then update their entire user list display or you tell them exactly which user has been removed or added and they then incrementally update their display based on the change.

To send the whole array to one specific socket, you would do something like this:

```
socket.emit('userList', userArray);
```

To send it to all connected uses, you would do this:

```
io.emit('userList', userArray);
```

In both cases, the client would listen for the `'userList'` message and then update their display accordingly.

```
socket.on('userList', userArray => {
    // refresh  the display to show the userArray
});
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I've already done; I'm emitting the array items[] to the server, which is sending it to the clients. The client-side then receives it and and displays it. However, it currently doesn't add usernames to the array ([James] -> [James, Bob] ->  [James, Bob, Paul]), but replaces the name of the first user to connect with consequent connecting user etc. ([James] -> [Bob] -> [Paul]).

Comment: @xstax - Then show us the EXACT and ACTUAL code where you think you're doing that.  The code you do show starts with an empty `items` array, adds one item to it and sends that to the server.  And, when you receive items from the server, you look like maybe you update the display, but you don't update the local copy of `items` so they next time you modify it, you're going to take an empty `items`, add one to it and then send that back to the server.

Comment: @xstax - This whole model seems flawed.  The server should keep the master list of items.  Clients should then ask to add or remove individual items from that list and the server can then resend the master list out to all clients after modifying the master list.

Comment: I tried the master list again, and I've managed to get it working. Realised a few issues with how I was emitting it, but managed to solve it.
Thanks for your firm help.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, just `socket.emit('eventName', array);`

But if you change items of array, it's not gonna change in all socket clients and/or server. You need to emit new array every time that array has changed. Otherwise sockets are not gonna update their values